# jinja2 fastapi, output dict to html not showing results

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

i am trying to pass my searched result to a html page with jinja2 from fastapi.

here is my back end

```
@app.get("/api/search")
async def get_card_price(request: Request, card_search_keyword: str):
    card_results = await get_card_price(card_search_keyword)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("results.html", {"request": request,
                                                       "card": card_results["card"],
                                                       "card2": card_results["card2"]})
```

and here is my sample data return

```
{
  "total_card2": 5,
  "total_card: 3,
  "card2": {
    "98275-JP": {
      "card_condition": "NM",
      "card_price": "¥ 6,500",
      "card_qty": "26",
      "other_condition": {}
    },
    "98709-JP": {
      "card_condition": "NM",
      "card_price": "¥ 6,500",
      "card_qty": "1",
      "other_condition": {}
    }
  },
  "card": {
    "LzgZK": {
      "card_name": "test2",
      "price_updated_date": "2022-01-20T09:05:16.314Z",
      "set_tag": "mh2",
      "rarity": "rare",
      "price_normal": 47.99,
      "price_foil": 99.99
    },
    "LKGxd": {
      "card_name": "test3,
      "price_updated_date": "2022-01-20T09:05:16.314Z",
      "set_tag": "mh2",
      "rarity": "rare",
      "price_normal": 49.99,
      "price_foil": 89.99
    },
    "k93K0": {
      "card_name": "test4",
      "price_updated_date": "2022-01-20T09:05:16.314Z",
      "set_tag": "pmh2",
      "rarity": "rare",
      "price_normal": null,
      "price_foil": 89.99
    }
  }
}
```

here is my sample html output trying to output card only section but not cards2 dict

```
{% for cards in card %}
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><img class="card-img-top mb-5 mb-md-0" src='{{ cards["card_img_id"] }}' alt="..." /></div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="small mb-1">{{ cards.card_name }}</div>
                        <h1 class="display-5 fw-bolder">{{ cards.card_name }}</h1>
                        <div class="fs-5 mb-5">
                            <span class="text-decoration-line-through">$45.00</span>
                            <span>$40.00</span>
                        </div>
                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium at dolorem quidem modi. Nam sequi consequatur obcaecati excepturi alias magni, accusamus eius blanditiis delectus ipsam minima ea iste laborum vero?</p>
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <input class="form-control text-center me-3" id="inputQuantity" type="num" value="1" style="max-width: 3rem" />
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-dark flex-shrink-0" type="button">
                                <i class="bi-cart-fill me-1"></i>
                                Add to cart
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /><br />
                 {% endfor %}
```

i can get 3 results from the loop but outputing from each of the card name and id is not shown out. i am not sure what did i do wrong here this time.

Comment: Where are you using either `card2` or `card` in your template? It seems like you're using `cards`, which isn't either of the values you're assigning to the templateresponse?

Comment: sorry that is my typo, is actually card instead of cards edited it, is still not printing the values

Comment: You probably want to switch the names around so that the variable given to the template is actually named `cards`; it's very hard to read now. Also, since you're using a dict, you're probably going to get the _key_ in the iteration, not the value. You can get all the values from the dict by iterating over the dictionary's values: `for card in cards.values()`

Comment: for card in cards.values() after using this, the value is printing instead. thanks alot, how about if i am interested in printing key and values as well?

Comment: You can use `items()` to get a tuple of both the key and the value: `for key, value in cards.items()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the same name when assigning the cards to the `TemplateResponse` as when you access it in the template (use `cards` in both places).

Since you're using a dict, you're going to get the *key* of the element when iterating over it with `for`, not the value.

You can get all the values from the dict by iterating over the dictionary's values instead:

```
{% for card in cards.values() %}
```

Another option if you need both the key and the value is to iterate over `items`:

```
{% for key, card in cards.items() %}
```